# Extract number seperated with "." from text

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed

I'm trying to find the best regular expression to extract a version number from a string.

i try to use this : `sed -ne 's/[^0-9]*\(\([0-9]\.\)\{1,8\}[0-9][0-9][^.]\).*/\1/p'`

For example:

```
net-backend:pom:0.0.220-SNAPSHOT
```

should extract : `0.0.220`

but in case :  `net-backend:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`

i can't extract the number

How i can resolv this ?

Thanks

Comment: In the second case, the second `[0-9]` can not match in `0.0.1`

Comment: Any time you find yourself saying something like `I'm trying to find the best regular expression to...` just keep in mind this very accurate observation: [Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

Comment: This might help: `tr -cd '0-9.\n' < file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pattern you are expecting to match at least 2 times a digit `[0-9]` followed by any char except a dot.

You could repeat the second character class 0+ times instead and omit `[^.]` as `0.0.1` has a single digit at the end.

```
sed -ne 's/[^0-9]*\(\([0-9]\.\)\{1,8\}[0-9][0-9]*\).*/\1/p' <<< "net-backend:pom:0.0.220-SNAPSHOT"
sed -ne 's/[^0-9]*\(\([0-9]\.\)\{1,8\}[0-9][0-9]*\).*/\1/p' <<< "net-backend:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
```

Output

```
0.0.220
0.0.1
```

Comment: These are for example pages where you can find a lot of information https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

anubhava has written a book about it :-)

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk. Use `:` and `-` as field separator and output second last field:

```
awk -F '[:-]' '{print $(NF-1)}' file
```

Output:

```
0.0.220
0.0.1
```

Comment: This will give wrong result if input is `"net-backend:pom:0.0.220"`

Comment: @anubhava right, but every other answer will also give the wrong result for some input other than what the OP told us they have to handle. Your answer would fail for `net-backend:foo:pom:0.0.220-SNAPSHOT`, for example. That one's an easy fix (use $NF instead of $3) but there may be different strings and you get the point - all we have to go on is the sample input the OP provides and if the real input doesn't look like that then YMMV.

Comment: @EdMorton: `net-backend:foo:pom:0.0.220-SNAPSHOT` is not a valid input because this is actually a dependency line from grade where format of each input is `group:name:version` (always 3 fields)

Comment: @anubhava I've never heard the expression `a dependency line from grade`, how do you know what's what this input is as opposed some other `:`-separated data?

Comment: An example line from my `build.gradle` is `compile('com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre')` where dependency is defined in this format `group:name:version`

Comment: Not sure that means that all lines of text that look kinda like that are for the same application with the same constraints but maybe you're right, idk.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`

```
awk '
match($0,/pom:[^-]*/){
  print substr($0,RSTART+4,RLENGTH-4)
}
' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** With `sed`

```
sed 's/.*pom:\([^-]*\).*/\1/' Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

An `awk` suites better here:

```
awk -F: '{sub(/-.*/, "", $3); print $3}' <<< "net-backend:pom:0.0.220-SNAPSHOT"
awk -F: '{sub(/-.*/, "", $3); print $3}' <<< "net-backend:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
```

```
0.0.220
0.0.1
```

Comment: FWIW I'd use `sub(/-.*/, ""); print $NF` - it'll be a bit more robust for more/unexpected `:`s in the input string (making assumptions about how such should be handled of course!).

Comment: Yes I can make it `$NF` also but there are always 3 fields in a gradle dependency

Answer (score 2):

Just pure linux command you can do:

```
echo "net-backend:pom:0.0.220-SNAPSHOT" | cut -d':' -f3 | cut -d'-' -f1
```

```
0.0.220
```

There are other pattern scanning and processing language such as `awk`. However, for a simple application like that, assuming you'd always have the same standard string I'd just use `cut`.

Comment: What I was about to say is for a simple string like that it is not necessary to use other languages just to cut the string.

Answer (score 0):

Awk, `match` and regex:

```
$ awk '
match($0,/([0-9]+\.?)+/) {
    print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
}' file
```

Output:

```
0.0.220
0.0.1
```

If there are multiple matches on a line, you got to wrap a `while` around it:

```
awk '{
    while(match($0,/([0-9]+\.?)+/)) {
        print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
}' <<< a0.0.1b0.0.2
```

Output:

```
0.0.1
0.0.2
```